# Dplyr's select function throws an error in Rscript

Tags: r, dplyr, rscript

I was trying to run `Rscript dosth.R` in the command line. In the script, I used `select` function from `dplyr` package. I got the following error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("select_") :
no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "factor"
Calls: %>% ... withVisible -> -> select -> select.default -> select_
Execution halted
```

However, I could successfully run the main function inside this "dosth.R" script in RStudio.

I want to solve this problem because eventually I would like to put all the codes in a script which can be run in the command line.

I wonder whether you have met this problem and would greatly appreciate your kind help.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the code for "dosith.R" if it doesn't have any sensitive data? Then I can try to reproduce the issue you have. Perhaps using a service such as: https://pastebin.com/

Comment: Please share sample of your data using `dput()` (not `str` or `head` or picture/screenshot) and the code you're working on so others can help. 
See more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that somewhere in your code you redifined `data.frame` object into `factor`. The simulation below throws exactly the same error as you defined:

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
iris <- factor(1:10)
iris %>% select(Sepal.Width)
```

> Error in UseMethod("select_") : no applicable method for 'select_'
>   applied to an object of class "factor" Calls: %>% ... withVisible ->
>   -> select -> select.default -> select_ Execution halted

So please check and remove `data.frame` -> `factor` transformation from dosth.R file.